# The best voltage for corrosion removal electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis

What 'd be the optimum or best voltage value used in a corrosion removal electrolysis?

Comment: Depends on the corrosion.

Comment: Probably more of a chemistry question than an electricity question I'd say. IIRC each reaction you want to happen requires a certain voltage, so the optimum voltage would be slightly above the one for the reaction you want, so that you don't waste power on other reactions

Comment: Duplicate of: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37436/what-current-and-voltage-are-best-for-electrolysis-rust-removal (not that it's well answered at all..).

Answer (score 3):

Electrolytic rust removal on steels does *not* actually "revert" any rust back into "elemental iron". The whole point is merely to generate as many bubbles of hydrogen gas as quickly as possible to mechanically "debride/dislodge" the bulk rust away from the surface of the metal.

Once this occurs, any "newly-exposed" iron (after the rust on top of it gets dislodged away into the solution) is immediately converted into [magnetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite) *by the water itself:* $$3\,\text{Fe}(s) + 
4\,\text{H}_2\text{O}(\ell) \to \text{Fe}_3\text{O}_4(s) + 4\,\text{H}_2(g)$$
which is responsible for that ["black oxide"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_oxide) layer often seen remaining on the metal after running the electrolysis setup as well.

Note that while this black oxide layer may *initially* help to passivate the underlying metal against corrosion/rusting, it too will eventually rust in time given enough exposure to water and oxygen as well:

- \$4\,\text{Fe}_3\text{O}_4(s) + \text{O}_2(g) \to 6\,\text{Fe}_2\text{O}_3(s)\$ [(plus any associated hydrates as well)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust)
- \$\text{Fe}_2\text{O}_3(s) + \text{H}_2\text{O}(\ell) \rightleftharpoons 2\,\text{FeO(OH)(s)}\$ [(plus any associated hydrates as well)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide)

So, with respect to the electrolysis setup, you'll generally want to

1. Run it using the highest currents possible to generate as much hydrogen gas as possible (a powerful DC current source would probably be ideal)...
2. Use a good electrolyte (like washing soda or even [sodium sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_sulfate), probably quite rather cheap as well!!) to reduce the resistance of the solution
3. Place the anodes *close to* (but not touching!) your workpiece (cathode) to also reduce the resistance of the solution as well
4. Place the anodes close to where the desired rust removal should take place (as hydrogen gas will be generated on those parts of the workpiece/cathode *facing* the anodes)
5. Use large graphite (and/or other inert) anodes in place of stainless steel anodes (as the former are reusable and non-sacrificial (with minimal degradation, assuming anodic current density is not too high), and could pose less of a risk of generating [hexavalent chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexavalent_chromium) than the latter as well)

---

**A couple of edits (based on the chat in the comments):

1. [Washing soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washing_soda) would likely be a much better electrolyte than [sodium sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_sulfate) as it

   - Forms a more concentrated saturated solution (3.2M for washing soda relative to 1.97M for sodium sulfate)
   - Does not generate [persulfates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persulfate) at the anode, which can help extend the life of the anode (and possibly the cathode as well)
   - Increases the pH which assists with both oxygen gas formation at the anode, as well as magnetite formation at the cathode (magnetite/black-oxide formation [requires alkaline environments](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Pourbaix_Diagram_of_Iron.svg)!)
2. Under sufficiently negative cathodic potentials, the electroplating of elemental iron back onto the cathode can become thermodynamically favorable. However, it *still* seems that hydrogen gas generation might still be the "[primary effect](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/124081/43057)" responsible for the "de-rusting" action of rust electrolysis, as

   - the ***kinetics*** of this activity seem unclear (short of a more formal study / reference / experiment!)
   - rust electrolysis is usually performed on significantly-rusted items to begin with, and often discolors initially clear electrolytic solutions with brown and rust-colored particles ([even with inert anodes like graphite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dJq8vza3PU))
   - bulk rust itself is a poor conductor of electricity, and quite insoluble in the alkaline solutions commonly used for rust electrolysis

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146823/discussion-on-answer-by-manrow-the-best-voltage-for-corrosion-removal-electrolys); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right the process is similar to a battery, whatever potential difference of the reaction you need to remove the ion or electron that's how much voltage you need to apply.

Most reactions would probably be similar to battery voltages with low voltage in the volts range and the current would increase the reaction